# jw player loader not working for on buffer event

Tags: javascript, video, jwplayer

the loader symbol is not working when we fast forward the video in jw player.

i am using javascript api of jw player. initially when the player starts if the video is not buffered it shows the loader sign but if i seek(fast forward) to sometime which is not buffered , the video gets freezed and once it is buffered  the video starts playing.

result: i want the loader sign instead of freezing the video.

```
.on('buffer', function () {
          window.clearTimeout(that.timeout);
          isLoading = true;
          videoContainer.addClass(that.options.videoLoadingClass);
          that.playingVideo = video;
 });
```